# discord.py - How do i move a users suggestion to another channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

me once again for the 7th time.
I'm making a suggestion command. When someone sends their suggestion, it should go to another channel. I have a log channel ID set ( **log_channel_id** ), the suggestion should go to that channel.

Code:

```
class View(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @discord.ui.button(label='Confirm', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def asdf(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="Your suggestion has been sent successfully.",embed=None,view=None)
        # the suggestion should be sent to another channel, i already have a channel ID set for it (log_channel_id)


@bot.tree.command(name="suggest", description="Make a suggestion with this command.")
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction, title: str, description: str):
    if interaction.user.id in blacklist:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Unable to execute command.\nReason: blacklisted", color=discord.Color.red())
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Is this information correct?", description=f"sdfsdfsdfsd", color=discord.Colour.random())
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{interaction.user.avatar.url}")
        embed.add_field(name=f"Title", value=f"{title}", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Description", value=f"{description}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"USER ID: {interaction.user.id}")
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=View(), ephemeral=True)
```

Anyone have a idea to get the suggestion the user set to the log ID? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got the log_channel_id correct then this will do the work:

```
class View(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, embed):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed = embed

    @discord.ui.button(label='Confirm', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def asdf(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="Your suggestion has been sent successfully.", embed=None, view=None)
        channel = interaction.guild.get_channel(log_channel_id)
        await channel.send(embed=self.embed)

@bot.tree.command(name="suggest", description="Make a suggestion with this command.")
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction, title: str, description: str):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Is this information correct?", description=f"sdfsdfsdfsd", color=discord.Colour.random())
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{interaction.user.avatar.url}")
    embed.add_field(name=f"Title", value=f"{title}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Description", value=f"{description}")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"USER ID: {interaction.user.id}")

    view = View(embed)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=view, ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: it did work, all i had to do was replace ``await channel.send(embed=self.embed)`` with ``await bot.get_channel(log_channel_id).send(embed=self.embed)``

Comment: How am i supposed to make more buttons and make them appear after its sent? do I make another class?

Comment: It depends if you want the to appear together or not.
If you create one in the same class it will appear next to the previous one (like a confirm cancel thing)
If you create another class you need another command to trigger it and it will appear after each other as you trigger the commands (two separet button)

Comment: Remember what you did to send the message to the log channel? I'm trying to create buttons to that so I can do accept, deny, and all of that stuff.

Comment: wait i just got it lol nvm